# Writing a function for calculating min,max,sum, and average in C

Tags: c, algorithm, math, max, min

I need to write a function called void stat() in which the user inputs as my doubles as he wants and then types in a char when he is done. The function is supposed to calculate and output max, min, sum, and average. I have done everything except for the min. Could someone please help me out. Thank You!!!

```
void stat(){
    double x=0;
    double min=0, max=0, sum=0, average=0,i=0;
    int beenHere = 0;
    printf("enter numbers for stat()\n");

    while (scanf_s ("%lf", &x ) ==1 ){
        if (!beenHere || max < x)
            max = x;
        sum += x;
        i++;
        average = sum/ i;
        beenHere = 1;
    }//while

    printf("minimum: %f\n", max);
    printf("maximum: %f\n", max);
    printf("sum: %f\n", sum);
    printf("average: %f\n", average);
}//stat`
```

Comment: What are you missing here? It's the same check as with the max, just check for smaller values and that's it.

Comment: What part are you stuck on? Min should be pretty easy if you got max.

Comment: if **you** did the 'max' part of assignment, what is the problem with min?

Comment: figured it out printf("minimum: %f\n", max);
   should be printf("minimum: %f\n", min);

Comment: Your code doesn't anything about min though

Comment: You do actually need to compute the minimum, too... not just print `0`...

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode for **max**:

```
double max = 0.0;
foreach element:
    if element > max:
        max = element;  // consider it new max
```

The difference with **min** is that you need to start with big value:

```
double min = MAX;
foreach element:
    if element < min:
        min = element;  // consider it new min
```

where `MAX` is a constant bigger than possible value of any element.
A possible `MAX` could be `DBL_MAX` from `<float.h>`, value of which is about  1 x 10<sup>37</sup>